# How can I change the number format of a cell in a database-imported table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a sheet that looks like this -

```
    A  |     B      | C
   ----------------------
    2  |  Okay      |  0
    3  |  Not okay  | 0
```

Cell `C3` has the green error pointer and says "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe", and of course it's left-justified.

When I display the format for both cells `C2` and `C3`, they both show as "General".

When I use VBA to examine “NumberFormat”, both appear as “General".

I am using Office 2010, by the way.

I would like to tidy this up (this happens to dozens of cells across a number of worksheets) by changing the format from text to general using VBA code, but how can I do this if it believes the cells in question are already formatted as General?

Comment: Is this data you've entered, or has it come from somewhere else?

Comment: It's come from somewhere else; an Excel add-in has run a query to fetch data from a database. It's very inconsistent, the vast majority of cells don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when Excel thinks the number is stored as text (even if it says it isn't, even if you change the format to number) because it was badly encoded on the other end.

A very simplistic fix for numbers stored as text is to add an extra column with a formula that converts the number to a number.

```
=$C2*1
```

And just drag that down, and then refer to that. If you're working with a live connected table, having this column at the end of the table will mean the formula range will expand with the data range.

Of course with VBA you could run a loop that goes through the data replacing each value in the column with the result of this formula.

Comment: Good idea, VBA loop did the job. Only worry now is that I'm changing cells I don't need to change because they don't have the problem. I can't ask if the cell is formatted as text as Excel doesn't think it is. Never mind

Answer (score 2):

Here's a VBA snippet that will do the trick.

```
Sub FixTextFormattedNumbers()
Dim s As Worksheet, r As Range
'Set target sheet and range
Set s = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set r = s.Range("A1:A10")

For Each c In r
    On Error Resume Next
    c.Value = CDbl(c.Value)
Next c
End Sub
```

The error-handling is just in case you have actual text in the specified range.

Answer (score 1):

This can often happen when copy-pasting or importing data.  If it's an entire column, the best way to fix it is is to basically re-import the column with greater control over Excel's assumptions as to what kind of data something is.

The way to do this is:

1. Highlight a column with this issue
2. Choose `Data`-> `Text To Columns`
3. Click `Finish` (Defaults work for this case--they are Delimited-> Tab -> General (format)).  If you ever had to do the reverse (re-import numbers but force them to be treated as text), you'd change the third option to Text

Comment: It's not en entire column. A column will typically have 900 rows and maybe 70 or 80 of them have this problem. I don't want to so this manually, assumed this could be handled by VBA code, but it seems not.